# How to move div to right and left side using css

Tags: css

I am trying to move the div ( .div1 and .div2 ) when i click the show option. In the open condition these two div move to the right side. In the close or collapse condition these two div move to the left side. How to do it using only CSS.
If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

```
   .div1{
     position:relative;
   }
   .div2{
   position:absolute;
   }
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question please, not on another site

Comment: Your question is unclear, so please edit it to improve it. Firstly, I'm having trouble understanding your goal, so perhaps draw a sketch of what you want, take a photo of it and include that in your question. Secondly, include the code you have written which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the "In the close or collapse condition", what exactly are you using to handle close or collapse condition?

I would imagine something like this would be a good starting point for you

```
.div1 {
   float: left;
}
.div2{
   float: left;
}
.wrapper-div:focus .div1{
   float: right;
}
.wrapper-div:focus .div2{
   float: right;
}
```